# TYPO3 - hook / signal after page rendered

Tags: typo3

Is there any hook/signal or anything else so that I can modify final HTML code of frontend page rendered by TYPO3?

My use case is:
I want to apply some regex and logging for links that are displayed across whole website - no matter if the link is rendered via tt_content bodytext (typolink or hardcoded) or by frontend plugin or comes via typoscript or possibly any other way.

Answer (score 2):

The `PAGE` object in TypoScript has `stdWrap`, so you can use `userFunc` there.

```
page = PAGE
page {
  ...
  stdWrap.userFunc = Your\NameSpace\YourClass->doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use real hooks instead of `stdWrap` you can look at the function [generatePage_postProcessing](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php#L2597-L2631) which has three hooks. In the [CoreApi Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Hooks/Configuration/Index.html#hook-configuration) you can find the way how to use hooks.

In your `ext_localconf.php` you can define your hook usage. As example:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['contentPostProc-all'][] = My\NameSpace\Hooks\PageGenerateHooks::class . '->contentPostProcAll'
```

Now in your hook class you can modify the content:

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController;

class PageGenerateHooks
{

  /*
   * \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController $pObj
   */
  public function contentPostProcAll(TypoScriptFrontendController $pObj)
  {
     $pObj->content = preg_replace('#mySearch#i','myTerm', $pObj->content;
  }

}
```

Comment: Seems it is not final html code delivered to user - there are some markers like <!--INT_SCRIPT.e7bfedbe02843b1361aa8ebc1e143bb4--> in the code still.

Comment: Seems like TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['hook_eofe']  is what I have searched for.